# Understanding the Todd-Coxeter Coset Enumeration Algorithm.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I've just finished reading [**Chapter 6**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H004AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=presentations+of+groups+johnson+"6.+coset+enumeration"&source=bl&ots=Qwlg9RzdkS&sig=trMCn7_t-DOh-QlND2B0OkA9bjU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHyManppbYAhVHJlAKHXGZDU8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=presentations%20of%20groups%20johnson%20%226.%20coset%20enumeration%22&f=false) of [*"Presentations of Groups,"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521585422) by D. L. Johnson.

### The Details:

Quoting Johnson . . .

> **Definition 1:** Let $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ be a finite group and put $F=\langle X\mid\rangle$, $\overline{R}=N$, so that $G$ is isomorphic to the factor group $F/N$; then to perform a *coset enumeration* on $G$ is simply to count the cosets of $N$ in $F$ (or $E$ in $G$), that is, to find $\lvert G\rvert$.

The group $E$ is understood to be trivial.

### Quoting Johnson . . .

> For each $$r=x_1\dots x_n\in R,$$ with $x_1\dots x_n$ a reduced word in $X\cup X^{-1}$, we draw a rectangular table having $n+1$ columns and a certain (for the moment unlimited) number of rows; thus
>
> $$\begin{array}{c |c| c |c| c | c |c| c}  & x_1 &  & x_2 & \dots & x_n &  \\
> \hline
> 1 & & 2 & & \dots & & 1 \\
> \hline
> 2 & & & & \dots & & 2 \\
> \hline
>  & & & & & & 
> \end{array}$$
>
> We begin by entering the symbol "$1$" in the first and last places of the first row of each table, the remaining places in the first rows being as yet empty. [ . . . ] Suppose the situation to be as in the above diagram with $2$ immediately to the right of $1$ and with $x_1\in X\cup X^{-1}$ lying between them. Now we put $2$ in the first and last places of the second row in each table and, *wherever in any table $1$ lies to the left of an empty space with $x_1$ between the two spaces or to the right of any empty space with $x_1^{-1}$ between the spaces, we fill that empty space with a $2$.*

So far so good (I think). I get the bit in italics, but where do the other $1$s come from?

Continuing to quote Johnson . . .

> Similarly, if $2$ lies to the right (left) of an empty space with $x_1$ $(x_1^{-1})$ between the spaces, we fill in that space with a $1$. The idea behind this process (which we call "scanning") is that $1$ and $2$ correspond to $e$ and $x_1$ of $G$, so that we may write $1x_1=2$ and $2x_1^{-1}=1$.

Again, so far so good . . .

> Having made sure that no more spaces can be filled in this way, we fill in an empty space with the new symbol $3$, begin a new row of the tables and scan as above, entering all possible $1$s, $2$s, and $3$s in accordance with the definitions of $2$ and $3$.

What definitions? Does he mean $2$ and $3$ corresponding with $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively? I don't see how to do that if so.

Further . . .

> Then fill a new empty space with the symbol $4$, begin the fourth row of the tables and *scan again*.

What is meant by "scan again"?

### The Question:

> Would someone explain to me the Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration algorithm, please?

Please help :)

*NB: I've read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd%E2%80%93Coxeter_algorithm) on the Todd-Coxeter algorithm, but it doesn't illuminate things for me, unfortunately.*

Comment: The best way to learn this algorithm is to do examples. It is difficult to explain it clearly, and I think Johnson does a reasonably good job of that. Try working through the examples in the book. I don't understand your first question. What other $1$s? $1x_1 = 2$ is the definition of $2$. Every number other than $1$ that arises in the table is introduced using a definition.  He explained what "scanning" means.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt. It's hard for me to do an example when I don't understand how to implement the algorithm. I suppose I mean the $1$s other than those initially stated at the start & end of the first row(s). I still don't understand "scanning", I'm afraid.

Comment: Scanning a row means looking at all of the entries already in the row. If there is an entry, say $3$, in one place, and a blank to the right of it, then you look at the generator between the $3$ and the empty place. If it is $x_4$, for example, then you check whether $3x_4$ is defined. If so, say $3x_4 = 5$, then you can put a $5$ in the empty place. Similarly for an empty place to the left of the $3$, but then, if the generator was $x_2$, you would check whether $3x_2^{-1}$ was defined. During this process other $1$s might occur in the middle of rows.